# Kubernetes flow in case of pod crash

Tags: kubernetes

Even if I don't configure any liveliness/Readiness probes, how Kubernetes detects my pod crash and then restart it. Can someone know the flow of Kubernetes in such case.
Thanks

Comment: Any idea folks ?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes also detects if the process with ID 1 inside the container is still running. If not, it will restart the pod.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Johnson. It would be great if you can please share, how Kubernetes detects if the process with ID 1 is alive or not. Does it poll or it gets events ? If it is poll, how much is the polling interval(what is its configuration parameter). If it gets events, how is the delay being added in the event. Thanks